# Get a label address out of the function scope in gcc/clang (C++)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, goto, jump-table

I'm making some kind of interpreter and I'm computing a static const jump table thanks to local label addresses.
You know the drill,
`static const int JUMP_TABLE[] = { &&case0 - &&case0, &&case1 - &&case0` and so on.
For various reasons, mostly performance, I'd like to copy/compress this table in an object during init.
I'm hurting my head against the wall because I can't figure how to escape the lexical scoping of the function !
 How can I somehow reference &&case0 from another function ?
Does somebody have a good trick for this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how this wouldn't destroy the stack unless the compiler preserves it in such a way that you might as well be calling actual functions.

Comment: @chris: The question does not say they want to jump to a target from outside the function in which it is defined, just that they want to compute with it. Presumably the computation results would be used inside the function.

Comment: I don't want to jump from another function, I want to read the offset in a table that is not static const.To do some checking, to compress it, and to access it with live registers, not by loading constants in .text.

Comment: Sorry, I vastly misunderstood the question.

Comment: No problem @chris, the issue is that I don't know what the solution looks like so I can't really show code. And I'm not a native speaker so my description might be... a bit unclear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of ways to achieve this within pure GNU C so approaches below use other mechanisms.

## Double compilation

You can compile your object file twice, collecting offsets on the first run and using them on the second. For example

```
int foo(int x) {
#ifdef GENERATE_ADDRESSES
    static __attribute__((section(".foo_offsets"))) unsigned offsets[] = { &&case0 - &&case0, &&case1 - &&case0 };
#endif
    switch (x) {
case0:
        case 0:
            return 1;
case1:
        case 1:
            return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can compile, extract bytes from `.foo_offsets` section and embed them to you app on second run

```
$ gcc tmp.c -c -DGENERATE_ADDRESSES
$ objcopy -j .foo_offsets -O binary tmp.o
$ xxd -i tmp.o | tee offsets.inc
unsigned char tmp_o[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
unsigned int tmp_o_len = 8;
```

## Inline assembly

You can use inline assembly to globalize labels:

```
extern char foo_case0[];
extern char foo_case1[];
const void *foo_addresses[] = { &foo_case0[0], &foo_case1[0] };

int foo(int x) {
    switch (x) {
        case 0:
asm("foo_case0:");
            return 1;
        case 1:
asm("foo_case1:");
            return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately in this case you can only collect *addresses* (not offsets) so you'll need to manually compute offsets at startup.

Comment: Thank you so much, the second way is exactly what I need ! It's self-contained, and I can pay the footprint of computing my table at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Goto is simply the best solution. Tho very rare. Its still part of c++ after many years for a good reason

So what i did was create a global bool and set it after I initialize my address array. So the first time my interpreter function is called,  it loads a structure of addresses so everything is within the same function.

Then with a little study of the assemblers output i was able to save a few ticks by arranging my code as follows.

if(is_initialized) .. ex command
else ... initialize stuff. Goto ex command

use a goto to jump back to the top and execute the command.
My interpreter is using almost 200 commands.

With a switch statement it was taking 5-1100 ticks. Depending on how far down the list the command was

Using goto functions[command]  has it down to 14 regardless of where the command is in the list

This provides a method that is purely c++ but not supported on all compilers